# on subsets with even intersection

Tags: combinatorics

Let $\wp_n$ be the family of all subsets of $[n]$.

Let $F_p, F_q\subseteq \wp_n$ s.t. $F_p\neq F_q$.

Then, prove that $|\{F_i\subseteq \wp_n\mid | F_i\cap (F_p\bigtriangleup F_q)| \text{ is even}\}| = 2^{n-1}$.

I already know how to prove it, but my proof goes by case-reasoning. Is there a clever "one-line proof" for this one ? 
( well, I would be content even with "two or three lines proof" :-) )

Comment: You should have either $F_p,F_q,F_i\in\wp_n$ or $F_p,F_q,F_i\subseteq[n]$, but not $F_p,F_q,F_i\subseteq\wp_n$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The presence of $F_p\bigtriangleup F_q$ is a red herring; the underlying fact is that $\#\{F_i\subseteq [n] \colon \#(F_i\cap G) \text{ is even}\} = 2^{n-1}$ for any *nonempty* subset $G$ of $[n]$.

To prove this, let $g$ be any element of $G$. The subsets of $[n]$ can be partitioned into $2^{n-1}$ pairs of the form $F$, $F \bigtriangleup \{g\}$; exactly one element of each pair has an intersection with $G$ of even cardinality.